# Generating Javascript view block with CakePHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, cakephp

Consider a URL like this:

```
http://site.com/upload/qeSJGs,ZWURb4,qdMMTZ,yM62UX,RlwwWT,ecw7s1
```

I need to get all of the 6 character strings separated by `,` into a Javascript array and inserted into my page. Here's my controller action:

```
public function upload($imageHashes) {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Uploads successful');
    $this->set('imageHashes', explode(',', $imageHashes);
    $this->layout = 'complex';
}
```

and in my view file I have this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->scriptBlock('', array('inline' => false)); ?>
```

Now, it's going to be mighty messy to write all the Javascript in the `scriptBlock` method, but I can't include an external Javascript file because the content changes based on the URL. Is there an easier way to do this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your imageHashes array and json_encode it.  Then for your script block you can just do something like

```
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock('var jsArray = ' . $json_encoded_array . ';', array('inline' => false));
```

Comment: No problem.  Was this the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 3):

For Cakephp 2.x and Cakephp 3.x You can use:

In View or Template file:

```
<?php $this->Html->scriptStart(array('block' => 'scriptBottom', 'inline' => false)); ?>

$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('OK');
});

<?php $this->Html->scriptEnd(); ?>
```

In Layout file:

```
<?= $this->fetch('scriptBottom'); ?>
```